# API fails in sending SMS to mobile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am facing a problem in sending an sms to mobile using this api, I get the acknowledgement i.e message sent successfully. But actually it deducts the message balance and shows the delivery fail.

```
static string sUserID = "Admin";
static string sPwd = "Admin@123";          
static string fromaddress = "Company Name";
static string ToAddress = "9999999999";
static string sMessage = "Test SMS From xyz person";

public ActionResult SMS()
{
    string sURL = "http://www.metamorphsystems.com/index.php/api/bulk-sms?username=" + sUserID + "&password=" + sPwd + "&from=" + fromaddress + "&to=" + ToAddress + "&message=" + sMessage + "&sms_type=" + 2 + "&filter_dnd=" + 1;
    string sResponse = GetResponse(sURL);
    Response.Write(sResponse);
    return View();
}

public static string GetResponse(string sURL)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sURL);
    request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4;
    CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials.UserName = sUserID;
    CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials.Password = sPwd;
    CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials.Domain = "http://www.metamorphsystems.com";
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    try
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        string sResponse = readStream.ReadToEnd();
        response.Close();
        readStream.Close();
        return sResponse;
    }
    catch
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Then you probably need to talk to your SMS provider!

Comment: Yeah I would also recommend to contact your sms provider or get a new sms provider.

Comment: When i send a message from my account given by the SMS provider. i am able to send it but not from my application. Do u still feel is there any problem with my code?

Comment: Thanks to All for Supporting me in getting the result. Finally i contacted to the sms provider there were few changes to be made. Its working now. Thanks a ton.